# How do I query a column to find the nearest values either side in sqlalchemy

Tags: python, sqlite, sqlalchemy

I can find the next value above or below but I can't seen to figure out how to get both with one query, and I feel like I've got myself lost in joins, aliased and `subqueries`?

so `if x = 2450:`

```
def get_next_XP_goal(xp):
    session = DbSessionFactory.create_session()

    xp_gaol = session.query(XPAchievement) \
        .filter(XPAchievement.XP_required > xp) \
        .order_by(XPAchievement.XP_required.asc()) \
        .first()

    return xp_gaol
```

which is `3100` which is great.

```
def get_previous_XP_goal(xp):
    session = DbSessionFactory.create_session()

    xp_gaol = session.query(XPAchievement) \
        .filter(XPAchievement.XP_required <= xp) \
        .order_by(XPAchievement.XP_required.desc()) \
        .first()

    return xp_gaol
```

which is `2200` which is great.

Answer (score 0):

you can use limit():

```
session.query(XPAchievement) \
    .filter(XPAchievement.XP_required <= xp) \
    .order_by(XPAchievement.XP_required.desc()) \
    .limit(3)
```

then first and the last are previous and next

Comment: Thanks but that only gives me 3 values less than x. I want the next highest value to x and the next lowest x

Comment: Right. if you want to do it in one query, i think it's going to be quite complex anyway. You may try to filter the id of previous and then use offset().

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom text function in sqlalchemy, the example below shows how you would do it with a datetime field and is specific to postrgesql but you can adapt it for different databases.

Date diff function

```
def datediff(cls, column, datetime):
    return text(f"ABS('{datetime}'::date - {column}::date)")
```

Then you can use in the query to order by the date difference

```
session.query(XPAchievement) \
    .filter(XPAchievement.XP_required <= xp) \
    .order_by(datediff('column', datetime) \
    .first()
```